# Goodness of fit for Gaussian process output using matlab?

Tags: gaussian, goodness-of-fit

I used `fitrgp` from gaussian process matlab toolbox and calculated the predicted values for a given observation. I calculated in three different cases and got three predicted values arrays say `ypred1`,`ypred2` and `ypred3`. Now I want to test the goodness of fit for these outputs in order to judge which algorithm values gives more accurate result. The details of `fitrgp` is given below link,

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/gaussian-process-regression-models.html

It would be grateful if anyone help me in this regard. Thank you in advace